# Painting Tape Application - One Foot Sections

Tags: painting, taping

I have read that one should apply painter's tape in single, one-foot sections instead of a long strip. The reason given is that when it is applied in one, long strip, the tape is stretched and won’t lay flat or stick properly, resulting in paint bleeding underneath the tape.

I just taped 70% of a 14' x 22' foot room with long strips. Is it worth re-taping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd argue it's not worth taping in the first place. Learn to '[cut in](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/video/0,,20803381,00.html)' with a brush and you'll save yourself all sorts of headaches in the future.

As for the advice, I have a hunch they don't mean literally tear off 1' sections of tapes, but apply it as-you-go foot by foot. Meaning, expose a foot of tape, rub it down good, expose more tape, rub that section down, repeat.

Comment: I've been seriously considering attempting the painting in technique but am hesitant because of how hard it's supposed to be. I'm sure it wasn't meant literally either but my strips are about 10 feet long each.

Comment: @Chris the key to cutting in is having a quality brush. And I would strongly encourage you to give it a try. It's not as hard as it looks and will save you so much time.

Comment: I'm sold. I hate taping...